# Postgres: count rows in jsonb for a specific key

Tags: json, postgresql, count, jsonb

I have a table with two labels: `id INT` and `value JSONB`. In `value` I have a json object `props` with keys `id_1`, `id_2`, and so on, with their respective values.

Is there a way to count the rows where the JSON object `props` has a specific key, such as `id_1`?

In this example, there should be two results: rows 1 and 4.

```
id   |   value
 1   |   {"name": "Jhon",  "props": {"id_1": {"role": "role1", "class": "class1"}, "id_2": {"role": "role2", "class": "class2"}}}
 2   |   {"name": "Frank", "role": ["role1", "role2"]}
 3   |   {"name": "Bob",  "props": {"id_3": {"role": "role3", "class": "class3"}, "id_4": {"role": "role4"}}}
 4   |   {"name": "Carl", "props": {"id_5": {"role": "role5", "class": "class5"}, "id_1": {"class": "class6"}}}
```

I tried something like this, but to make it work, I have to also specify the value, but the value could change for every row. For example, with this query, I only get one row back.

```
SELECT count(value)
FROM "myTable" 
where value->'props' ->> 'id_1' = '{"role": "role1", "class": "class1"}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT COUNT(z.*) FROM (    
SELECT id, value->'props'->>'id_1' as val FROM "myTable" ) z WHERE z.val
IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: it counts all the rows :(

Comment: Even after adding the **WHERE** clause?

Comment: @Brododipollo It will work fine after adding **WHERE z.val
IS NOT NULL**

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`?` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) to test whether a key exists, regardless of value.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM "myTable" 
where value -> 'props' ? 'id_1
```